# Location tracking

Tags: tracking

We went to the shops. I had my phone, but my husband's was left at home. When we got home, his phone asked him to rate his visit to the shop we had just been to. How is that possible? His phone is linked to my gmail account, but my phone didn't ask me to rate my visit.

Answer (score 2):

At least on an Android phone, with location services/history enabled, Google Maps may request ratings and other feedback when you go somewhere. Additionally, Google may use the location of a different device than the one you are currently using.

You said it yourself: your phone is linked to her Google account. Therefore, Google knew the location of the first phone, as it likely had location services enabled. The fact that the wrong phone gave the notification may simply be due to how Google Maps is configured on each phone.